# Python Scroll Speed

Tags: python, scroll, python-idle

Currently, on my Windows 7, Python 3.4.3 installation, the mouse wheel scrolls a blazing 2.5 lines at a time, both in the Idle text editor and the shell.

Windows 7 mouse is set to scroll 12 lines at a time.

Can I change Idle mouse settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console windows (Command Prompt, PowerShell) scroll according to the Control Panel => Mouse => Wheel lines setting. Firefox and Internet Explorer translate lines to pixels (with slightly different formulas).

At least on Win7 (what I currently have also), Tk text widgets scroll a fixed number of pixels on wheel clicks, which translates to 2 to 3 lines for font sizes 12 to 8. I opened a tracker issue to [override the default](https://bugs.python.org/issue25015).

Comment: I don't know if this is worth an edit, but the bug tracking has been migrated to GitHub some time ago. The (now closed) bug can be viewed here instead: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/69203